# How to give site owner the ability to change to footer text via theme options (1 post)

Tags: theme-options

I'm working on Settings API recently.
Now I can add my theme options item in admin menu.I can register my settings and create my section and fields.
And I think I can get the options using get_option(). But the problem is I can't find my way to implement those changes in my template file.
For Example I'll create a section and field for the site owner to give her the ability to change the footer text to whatever she want. Settings and textarea field appears correctly, but how can I tell WP to change that text as the site owner edit that text? what changes do I need to my theme's footer code to achieve this goal?

I'll appreciate if you can help me on this.

**Edit:** My Code in functions.php :

```
function m3n_admin_menu_init() {
    add_menu_page( 'M3N Theme Options', 'M3N Settings', 'manage_options', 'm3n-theme-options', 'm3n_menu_init' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'm3n_admin_menu_init' );

function m3n_menu_init() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>M3N Theme Settings</h2>';
      echo '<form action="options.php" method="POST">';
      settings_fields( 'm3n_settings_group' );
      do_settings_sections( 'm3n-theme-options' );
      submit_button();
      echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
}


function m3n_settings_init() {
    register_setting( 'm3n_settings_group', 'm3n_settings_name' );
    add_settings_section( 'section-one', 'General Settings', 'm3n_section_init', 'm3n-theme-options' );
    add_settings_field( 'field-one', 'Footer Settings', 'm3n_footer_field_init', 'm3n-theme-options', 'section-one' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'm3n_settings_init' );

function m3n_section_init() {
    echo '<p>Enter your text for Footer</p>';
}
function m3n_footer_field_init() {
    $options = get_option( 'm3n_settings_name' );
    echo '<textarea name="field-one" id="field-one" rows="3" value="' . $options . '"></textarea>';
}
```

Code inside footer.php :

```
<p><?php echo get_option( 'm3n_settings_name' ); ?></p>
```

Comment: Why don’t you use a widget?

Comment: because I want to have this ability in my theme out of the box. Also I want to learn this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have created a custom option using the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Lets say you have created an option called `footer-text` you can display it in your theme using `<?php echo get_option( 'footer-text' ); ?>`.

Essentially you are echoing the result that is stored in the `wp_options` table for the option called `footer-text`.

It is advised to include some of the code you have done already done, this shows you have attempted something and it makes it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Stemie. I included my code above. Could you please help me to complete the last function. I have problem with that.I mean m3n_footer_field_init() function which renders my actual settings field.

Comment: Have you tried `<?php echo get_option( 'field-one' ); ?>` in your footer.php after adding the text in the actual options section? Just as an aside this is a great plugin for options pages https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/ I generally use it as it's more convenient than a custom setup.

Comment: Thanks again, But I have problem at the start, even before I want to go to footer.php. Look at m3n_footer_field_init() function that render the input fields. I want to have a textarea there, which admin can enter their text for show in footer. After defining the $options variable, what should I write for my textarea input(name, id, value)? sorry for this kind of beginner questions but I'm novice in WP and I can't find my way through this. thanks in advance.

Comment: My codes had a major problem. I didn't write the form tag itself. oops... I add that and I think now everything is fine but still it doesn't work. I include my codes in functions.php and footer.php above. Please Let me know if there are any problem in it (obviously, it is). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake!!! the $option_name in register_setting function should match the option ID, but those two, didn't match in my codes. so that didn't work for me.
I changed $option_name argument in my register_setting & corresponding arguments in get_option, etc, and everything works just fine.
Thanks.